# How to make brew installed software take effect over the manually installed one?

Tags: macos, upgrade, install, homebrew

I have an older version of software that I once manually installed through installation package (version 0.6.6 -- I write it down here for later discussion purpose, but the version number is not relevant to this question).

Now I found brew is better why to manage the update/upgrade etc. So, I use brew to install the software by doing `brew install terraform` (version 0.6.9 -- again, I write it down here for later discussion purpose, but the version number is not relevant to this question), which is all good so far.

However, when I do `terraform version` to query the current effective version, I found it's still the old version.

My question is how I can make the brew installed software take over.

A side question is that which I try to find out terraform's location, by run `which terra (hit tab now)`, which I normally do for other software, the tab won't do the auto complete action for me. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to simply delete the old version of the software.

If you want to keep both, you'll need to change your `$PATH` environment variable so that the location of the new version appears before the location of the old version. Do this by editing `~/.bash_profile`.